# Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery. SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT SUM((qty * (SELECT gross_wt
                   FROM lpr_productmaster
                   WHERE productid = lpr_order_detail.productid))) AS prodwt
FROM lpr_order_detail
WHERE order_id = 413
GROUP BY order_id;
```

Comment: So... what is your question? The error is telling you the problem here.

Comment: How to write the query, please help into it, what should i do in this query

Comment: It would be nice if you actually ask a question inside your post. Instead of putting it only in the title. And perhaps also mention what error you got.

Comment: I would be great if you provide more information like table scheme with few data and expected output.

Comment: Without knowing what you're trying to achieve, sample data, expected results, we can't help you here. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and then [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53722589/edit) your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(qty * gross_wt) AS prodwt
FROM lpr_order_detail 
INNER JOIN lpr_productmaster
    ON lpr_order_detail.productid = lpr_productmaster.productid
WHERE order_id = 413
GROUP BY order_id;
```

The idea is to rewrite your query in order not to use a sub-query.